# Update the UITextView content dynamically in a specific range

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, text-to-speech

I need to update the words dynamically in UiTextView content while TTS is playing without refresh the page.

Problem: While tts playing for the each word delegate`(willSpeakRangeOfSpeechString:(NSRange)characterRange utterance:(AVSpeechUtterance *)utterance)` is calling. 
so at that time i am updating the text color using `NSMutableAttributedString`.

In this process the content in the textview is unstable because for each word page is refreshing.

so i need to update the text in textview without refreshing the page.

I wrote the code like this.

> NSMutableAttributedString *attrStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString
>   alloc] initWithString:_theContent ];
>
> [attrStr addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont
>   systemFontOfSize:self.fontSize] range:[self wholeArticleRange]];
>
> [attrStr addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor
>   redColor] range:theRange];
>
> textview.attributedText = attrStr;

--In android we used **spannable class** to do this way. Is there any class in IOS like this?

Kindly give us solution ASAP

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the text view's `textStorage` property, of type `NSTextStorage`, which is a subclass of `NSMutableString`. From there you can use any `NSMutableString` operation, including setting attributes on the various ranges, without sending an entirely new string to the text view (which will make it flicker).

Do not forget to call `beginEditing` and `endEditing` to group edits together if you have to make multiple calls, in order to improve performance.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote the code like this. I am new to the IOS so if i am wrong kindly correct me.

> - (NSMutableDictionary *)attDict {
>
>   if (!_attDict) {
>         _attDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
>
>   ```
>   UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:self.fontSize];
>   // UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"TimesNewRomanPSMT" size:self.fontSize];
>    [_attDict setObject:font forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
>   [_attDict setObject:[UIColor blueColor] forKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName];
>   ```
>
>   }
>     return _attDict; }
>
>   [[displayingArticleView contentView].textStorage
>     setAttributes:self.attDict range:theRange]    ;

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to replace any text in your UITextField with some other on the fly, You can use the string replacement method, Like

```
[textField.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"your string" withString:@"string to be replaced"];
```

This will Replace all occurrences of the target(string to be replaced) string with replacement.